# Can't pass a character string to require() in a function?

Tags: r

So I recently came across an issue with a simple function I'm attempting to write to check if a package is available, and download it if not.

However for some reason, when I pass a character string to require via a function it fails to recognise it (see simple example below)...

This works...

```
    p.f <- function(x) print(x)
    p.f("Hello")
   [1] "Hello"
```

As does this...

```
    (require("base"))
    [1] TRUE
```

But this doesn't...?

```
    p.f <- function(x) (require(x))
    p.f("base")
    Loading required package: x
    [1] FALSE
    Warning message:
    In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
    there is no package called ‘x’
```

Why does it fail to recognise the character string instead of x?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That’s a consequence of the way [`require`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/library.html) [evaluates its arguments](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html). You can get around this by passing the `character.only` argument:

```
p.f <- function(x) (require(x, character.only = TRUE))
```

Comment: Excellent, works perfectly, thought that was already set as such from the Warning message, thanks!

Comment: @VierodA `require` internally calls `library`, and in *that* call it sets the argument because it would otherwise run into the same error you ran into. ;-)